# how to Style my Php (Pdf)

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

Ok so i have copied my coding below .
I want to apply pdf format in php code and i have done successfully its working but i want to give it a style how can i apply styling on my pdf.
I have added a table but i want rows alternate background colors

Updates ~!!!!

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{

    function BasicTable($header)
{
    //Header


    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
    $this->SetTextColor(1);
    $this->SetDrawColor(128,11,4);
    $this->SetLineWidth(1.3);
    $this->SetFont('','');

    $this->SetFillColor(224,235,5);

    foreach($header as $col)

        $this->Cell(40,7,$col,1);
    $this->Ln();

    //Data
   }
}


function FancyTable($header)
{
    //Colors, line width and bold font
    $this->SetTextColor(255,131,13);
    $this->SetDrawColor(18,0,0);
    $this->SetLineWidth(.3);
    $this->SetFont('','B');
    //Header
    $w=array(40,35,40,45);
    for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)
        $this->Cell($w[$i],7,$header[$i],1,0,'C',1);
    $this->Ln();
    //Color and font restoration
    $this->SetFillColor(124,25,255);
    $this->SetTextColor(130);



}

}




$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,102);
$pdf->SetXY( 65 , 25 );
$pdf->Write(0, "Requisition Reports");

$pdf->Line(20 , 32 , 195 , 31);


$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,10);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',10);
$pdf->SetXY( 20 , 30 );
$pdf->Write(0, "Request ID");



$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,10);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',10);
$pdf->SetXY( 45, 30 );
$pdf->Write(0, "FOR :");


$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,10);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',10);
$pdf->SetXY( 70 , 30 );
$pdf->Write(0, "From :");

$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,10);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',10);
$pdf->SetXY( 95 , 30 );
$pdf->Write(0, "Date :");


$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,10);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',10);
$pdf->SetXY( 120, 30 );
$pdf->Write(0, "Item :");


$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,10);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',10);
$pdf->SetXY( 135, 30 );
$pdf->Write(0, "Description :");


$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,10);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',10);
$pdf->SetXY( 160, 30 );
$pdf->Write(0, "User");


$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,10);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',10);
$pdf->SetXY( 175, 30 );
$pdf->Write(0, "Status");



$querya=mysql_query("select * from request order by FIELD(Status,'done','pending');");

$b=35;
$ids=array();
$c=40;


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($querya)) {

$forname=$row['for'];
$fromname=$row['from'];
$req=$row['request_id'];

$queryb=mysql_query("select name from entities where id=$forname;");

    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryb)) {

        $forname=$row2['name'];

}       


$queryc=mysql_query("select name from entities where id=$fromname;");

    while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryc)) {

        $fromname=$row3['name'];

}       





$pdf->SetTextColor(124,12,10);

                $pdf->SetXY( 30 , $b );
                    $pdf->Cell(0,5,$req,1);

$pdf->SetTextColor(124,12,10);

                $pdf->SetXY( 45, $b );
                    $pdf->Cell(0,5,$forname);




$pdf->SetTextColor(124,12,10);

                $pdf->SetXY( 70 , $b );
                    $pdf->Cell(0,5,$fromname);




$pdf->SetTextColor(124,12,10);

                $pdf->SetXY( 95 , $b );
                $pdf->Cell(0,5,$row['request_date']);


$pdf->SetTextColor(124,12,10);

                $pdf->SetXY( 120 , $b );
                $pdf->Cell(0,5,$row['item_name']);


$pdf->SetTextColor(124,12,10);

                $pdf->SetXY( 135 , $b );

                $pdf->Cell(0,5,$row['description']);


$pdf->SetTextColor(124,12,10);

                $pdf->SetXY( 165 , $b );
                $pdf->Cell(0,5,$row['user']);



$pdf->SetTextColor(124,12,10);

                $pdf->SetXY( 175 , $b );
                $pdf->Cell(0,5,$row['status']);



        //if($row['status']=="done")
        //{

//$id=$row['request_id'];

//$queryd=mysql_query("select * from issue where request_id=$id;");

    //while ($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryd)) 
//{


        //$iss_date=$row4['issue_date'];


//$pdf->SetTextColor(11,11,120);
//$pdf->SetXY( 30, $c );
//$pdf->Write(0, "Issue Date:");


                //$pdf->SetXY( 50 , $c );
                //$pdf->Write(0, $row4['issue_date']);


//$pdf->SetTextColor(11,11,120);
//$pdf->SetXY( 75, $c );
//$pdf->Write(0, "Description:");


                //$pdf->SetXY( 95 , $c );
                //$pdf->Write(0, $row4['description']);


//$pdf->SetTextColor(11,11,120);

//$pdf->SetXY( 125, $c );
//$pdf->Write(0, "User:");


                //$pdf->SetXY( 140 , $c );
                //$pdf->Write(0, $row4['user']);
            //}


    //$header=array();      
            //$header=array($row4['issue_date'],$row4['description'],$row4['user']);


//}



$b+=15;
$c+=15;





}


$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: What type of style you want to apply?

Comment: like i need a table in in which rows have alternate colors.
I want to give label different colors so it look attractive and nice its working fine but i want apply styles only

Comment: Looks like you have erased too much. Where is the loop that creates the rows you want to style?

Comment: We need to see that loop of code. Please put it back in. When you reply to a user's comments always put `@username` to make sure they are notified that you replied to their comment. Replying to my comment? include @Kuya in your comment. Then the system will notify me that you have replied. Thanks.

Comment: @Kuya i have updated my code plz see